# In IEEE, after the article undergoes the major revision and accepted, do I have a chance to correct a small error and submit the final version?

Tags: publications, paper-submission, ieee

I have a journal paper submitted to the IEEE, and I have submitted the revised version for the major revision recently.

However, I have found a **small mistake** today, and this small error will not influence the main contributions of my paper, but this may mislead the readers.

I wonder if the revised manuscript is accepted by the IEEE, can I still have a chance to correct this **small** mistake?

Here I do not mean that the reviewers' work is not good, but this error is too cryptic to be detected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can make changes.  When submitting the final source, I often proofread a paper once more and fix any minor errors.  I have also carried out relatively major changes.  For example, I've even broken up a long mathematical expression that runs across the column boundary into multiple parts.